# Geodjango: importing data from OSGB_1936, displaying in WGS84?

Tags: mapping, openstreetmap, geodjango, proj4js, proj

I have some polygon data saved in a PostGIS database with projection SRID 27700.

```
geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=27700)
```

I want to display the shapes on OpenStreetMap, i.e. with SRID 900913 (I think?).

So, two questions:

1. How do I change the code below to
   output with the right SRID for
   OpenStreetMap?
2. How can I change the
   Django code below to give me a nice json
   object, ready to display as a
   polygon?

```
area = get_object_or_404(soa.objects, code=my_code)
polygon = area.geom
return render_to_response('area.html', { 'area': area }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Apologies if this question doesn't make sense - I'm pretty new to GeoDjango.

Comment: Apologies - can't get 2nd code extract formatted correctly, no matter what I do. Weird.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the formatting somewhere: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58039/code-not-formatted-in-this-answer

Answer (score 1):

With GeoDjango, use [transform](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.transform) to change a geometry's projection, and [json](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.geojson) or [wkt](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.wkt) for output.  It should be as simple as:

```
polygon.transform(900913)
return render_to_response('area.html', {'area': area, 'polygon': polygon.json})
```

`json` method will give you GeoJSON; you can use `wkt` if you prefer.  A map API like OpenLayers will handle either.